# Different connections on positive and negative pins in PCB design

Tags: pcb

I've seen some designs they have connected pins of power components differently.

For example in a buck capacitor at the output of a DC to DC power supply I've seen the positive pin on direct connection and the negative pin on thermal relief connection or with just one via to the ground.

In the picture below you can see a solid state SMD capacitor (both pins have the same size) is directly connected to the positive pin having a much lower impedance but the negative pin is connected to ground with just one via and a thin trace. The pads have the same size.

[image: capacitor connections]

I'd like to know if there's any good reason behind that or if the engineer did not understand how the current flows.

Isn't that a mistake? Shouldn't both pins have the same impedance path to the power rails?

Comment: Can you provide some more context? It is hard to say if it is a mistake - often you have multiple tradeoffs to balance. Perhaps the positive pad was much bigger because it also acts as heatsink for a large switching transistor or such.

Comment: My example is a solid state SMD capacitor on the output of a DC to DC power supply. Both pins are the same in size.

Comment: There appears to be no connection to the bigger pad - why is that?

Comment: @Andy aka, it's an example, I can't post the  real design. In the design the polygon pour just continues to the board supplying the other circuits.

Comment: What part number is the capacitor?

Comment: Where's the capacitor?

Comment: @andyaka UWT1E471MNL1GS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I'd like to know if there's any good reason behind that*

The part is a 470 uF 25 volt electrolytic capacitor like this: -

[image]

So, it will have a fairly high ESR (effective series resistance) that will dwarf the resistance of the via to ground and the short copper track. In effect the way that it is mounted will have little effect on its performance.

If it were a non-electrolytic device used in high frequency circuits where the capacitor were expected to deliver anything other than bulk capacitance then how it is mounted with respect to the power rails could be very important.

> *Shouldn't both pins have the same impedance path to the power rails?*

Ideally yes, but in practice for a bulk electrolytic capacitor, you could put it in series with 0.5 ohms and it would, more than likely in 99% of applications, work perfectly as required by the circuit.

Comment: Same practice I see even in ceramic capacitors, 0805, 1206, or 1210. My question wasn't about electrolytic capacitors but more generic. But I think your last sentence answers the question.

Comment: @MrBit I reckon that even the ubiquitous "100 nF across each chip supply" could by done this way if the Vcc was fed on the top copper. I would even go as far to say that adding thermal vias around the upper positive Vcc connection wouldn't be a problem either.

Comment: @Any aka I was confused because in the design I saw every component associated with power circuitries was connected in exactly that way. Pins on positive rails directly connected but something wrong seemed to happen on pins on negative rail cause they looked so neglected. I tried to give a good example of what I saw and it is actually pretty accurate.

Comment: I am surprised only that they didn't use thermal reliefs.

Comment: exactly. I think the very poor connection of the pin that goes to GND voids the meaning of the direct connection on the top. It doesn't make much sense to me. I'd use thermal reliefs on positive pin.